# iOS Button Difference Between Simulator and Device

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

Building an older app with XCode 5 uses the new button style on the simulators (iOS7) but when deployed to an actual device, the buttons on the Navigation Bar revert to the pre-iOS7 style (black background).

If the Deployment Target is changed from 6.0 to 7.0, it works as expected on both the simulator and device. What else needs to be changed to get the new button style?

Comment: what is device OS version? if you run it on 6.0 it display pre-iOS7 style (black background).

Comment: Device version is iOS7 (iPhone 5S and 4). I don't have a pre-iOS7 device but the iOS6 simulator shows the expected buttons with black background.

Comment: In iOS6 simulator it shows buttons with black background.and in iOS7 it will show  new button style.so whats the problem??

Comment: On the iOS7 simulator, it shows the expected iOS7 buttons. On an actual iOS7 device, it shows iOS6 style buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode is building against the wrong iOS SDK (see [duplicate device scheme in xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479268/duplicate-device-scheme-in-xcode-4) for someone having a similar issue).

The 6.1 SDK is installed alongside 7.0. This causes there two be two entries in the target menu for a single device. If the first device is selected, everything builds and works as expected.

When the second phone target is selected, it is building against the 6.1 SDK. There is no indication in the menu which SDK is being used.